# Full Calendar slot showing 2 hours from start time for single slot

Tags: fullcalendar

I have calander for reminder. So im using start time only. not end time. Im giving one text field for start time.

Example : start time : 10.30 am means in week , it shows 10:30 am  to 12:30 pm.
So how can i show this to only 10:30am to 11:00 am ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [defaultTimedEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultTimedEventDuration/) property:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',    
    ...
});
```

Comment: I have calendar with multi dates selection. But there i cant use this. It always shows  start time correct but end time it shows 12pm.... :(

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what do you mean by multi dates selection, but maybe this property will do? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/defaultAllDayEventDuration/ ?

Comment: Dragging 2 dates gets selected 2 dates, example 19/12/2016 and 20/12/2016. then start date is 19/12/2016. but end date is 21/12/2016. how to make end date to 20/12/2016 ??

Comment: Is it possible for you to share some code (fiddle?)